# /etc/environment.d does not take effect on Archlinux

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, arch-linux

I believe  [systemd-environment-d-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html) parses conf files under `/etc/environment.d/`.

```
cat /etc/environment.d/60-foo.conf
FOO=xxx
```

But even after reboot, the environment variable 'FOO' does not appear in user processes.

How to let my systemd take cake of `/etc/environment.d/*` files?

- Distribution

  Archlinux x86_64
- systemd version

  systemd 251 (251.4-1-arch)

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of this: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12938

`/etc/environment.d/` only affects services, not user sessions.

For my purposes (adding a directory to `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`), adding the following to `/etc/profile.d/something.sh` works fine:

```
[testuser@fedora ~]$ cat /etc/profile.d/portmaster.sh
XDG_DATA_DIRS="/var/lib/portmaster/exports/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"
```